# customise output text based column width JSF

Tags: jsf, datatable

I have a code xhtml:

```
<p:column rendered="#{searchBean.eventDate}" 
            <h:outputText title="#{event.getYears(event.launchDate)}" value="#{event.phaseMission.length() gt 11 ? event.phaseMission.substring(0,11).concat('...') : event.phaseMission}"/>
</p:column>
```

Here, i tried to cut string inside output text by 11 characters, because width is fixed. But if a width is not fixed, how could I get width to compare with this text and after use concat?

Comment: you can set **minWidth** to  h:outputText so you after when ever text is bigger then minwidth that time automatically append your span

Comment: i did it, but the text is cutted automatique but i want 3 charactere ... It means, by exemple: textabc...

Comment: Okei, i found it, just use css text-overflow: ellipsis; :D